# How to open specific book on kindle by objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, kindle, custom-url

I'm developing an app related to books, in the book list the user marked the book they also have on amazon kindle, then when they click the "READ" button, the kindle app (iOS) open with that book opened.

my question is how to do it. I can open the kindle app with custom-url 
`kindle://what-next?`

but it just opens the kindle app, and I don't know how to do next.
I tried `kindle://book?action=open&asin={book-id}` with no luck.
(book-id from the amazon website url)
In my kindle app I have the free sample of that book and I have to click to choose what to open.

Any one know how to do it or any ideal how to work around would be really appreciated.

Updated: I tried `kindle://book?action=open&asin=B01MY0FRTE&location=40` on MacOS and it works but sadly it was ignored on iOS

Comment: @Cœur Do you have any experience on this ? or Do you know any one who can help me ? It would be really appreciated.

Comment: You have to ask the developer of Kindle app for the deep linking "API" / custom url scheme. You can't blind guess.

Comment: @Raptor So you mean no way if I don't talk to developer of Kindle ?

Comment: Yes, unless there is documentation somewhere.

Comment: @Raptor actually I followed the link below but it's a bit different
http://www.tjsg-kokoro.com/2015/04/07/workflowy-kindle-url/http://www.tjsg-kokoro.com/2015/04/07/workflowy-kindle-url/

Comment: luckily I know a little Japanese. The article is from 2015, and it's not an official document. Therefore there is a high chance that the information is no longer valid.

Comment: Yes you'r right. Then I'm getting stuck here. Hope some one who develop kindle could send me some advices.